# NLog Config files for different environments in Nuget Package

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nlog, nuget-package

I am using the Nuget [Packager extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/daf5c6db-386b-4994-bdd7-b6cd52f11b72) to create a Nuget Package to include my Logger project and Nlog. I have this working correctly but had a question about how do i use the correct config file for multiple environments (Dev/QA/Prod)?

Do I have multiple config files, one for each environment in the package? but how does the correct one get applied in QA for example, since different environments might have different listeners or targets? Whats the best way to accomplish this, an example to show how to do this would be great since i am new to Nuget and Nlog.Thanks for your help!

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Environment-specific-NLog-Logging-Configuration

Answer (score 1):

Nlog supports different locations of its config file. One of the location is the main configuration file of application. For more information please see [Nlog documentation](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#wiki-configuration-file-locations)

Then we can use config transformations option. Visual studio supports this by default for web firendly projects (ASP.NET MVC, WCF etc.). If you application is of different type you can use  an extension called [SlowCheetah](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WillBuikMSFT.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms)([NuGet Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlowCheetah/)). More information can be found at [this page](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx).

Config transformation deped on build configurations in visual studio. In web project you can see that web.config has two transformations: web.Debug.config and web.Release.config.

Hope it helps